# iOS 8 Swift Xcode 6 - Set top nav bar bg color and height

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, navbar

I have looked everywhere and tested all the code snippets posted on Stack, but nothing works for me as I need it to work.

I simply want to set:

- Nav bar height
- Nav bar bg color in RGB
- Nav bar centered logo

I'm working with iOS8, Xcode 6 and Swift.

Many thanks for a clear answer!

This is my code in ViewController.swift

```
// Set nav bar height

    navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y = -10

    // Set nav bar bg color

    var navBarColor = UIColor(red: 4 / 255, green: 47 / 255, blue: 66 / 255, alpha: 1)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = navBarColor

    // Set nav bar logo

    let navBarImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))

    navBarImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

    let navBarImage = UIImage(named: "navBarLogo.png")

    navBarImageView.image = navBarImage

    navigationItem.titleView = navBarImageView
```

Comment: Instead of calling navBar.titleView change it navigationItem.titleView, and for changing the frame call navigationController.navigationBar.frame.....Make sure you set an image for the imageView or it will look like nothing happened!

Comment: Thanks! Now the color and the bg image is working, but I cant seem to set a custom height for the nav bar? See updated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nav bar height:

In a custom navigation controller subclass...

The trick with this one is to NOT change the actual height of the navigation bar and instead adjust its origin.

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationBar.frame.origin.y = -10 
}
```

Nav bar bg color in RGB:

In a custom navigation controller subclass...

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationBar.barTintColor = // YOUR COLOR
}
```

or use the appearance proxy

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = // YOUR COLOR
```

Nav bar centered logo

In a custom view controller...

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: // YOUR LOGO)
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you still are having trouble with anything :)

Comment: This does not work reliably. See the link for the reason why.  You need to subclass. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28708356/4577867

Answer (score 12):

After applying the code in the accepted answer, the height doesn't seem to change at all..

It's not an easy job...and I've surveyed several articles online (most of them in Objective-C).

The most useful one is this: http://www.emdentec.com/blog/2014/2/25/hacking-uinavigationbar

But its final solution does not put items in the middle, and it's not in Swift.

*So I come up with a workable version in **Swift**.* Hope it helps some people as I was saved so many precious time on SO.

**Solution in Swift:**

The following code will solve some issues you may have encountered:

- The title & items are not placed in the middle of the navigation bar
- The title & items would flick when the user navigates between view controllers

You need to subclass the **UINavigationBar** first, and in your storyboard, select the navigation bar element, and in the **"Identity Inspector"** tab, set the new class as the Custom Class

```
import UIKit

class UINavigationBarTaller: UINavigationBar {
    ///The height you want your navigation bar to be of
    static let navigationBarHeight: CGFloat = 64

    ///The difference between new height and default height
    static let heightIncrease:CGFloat = navigationBarHeight - 44

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        let shift = UINavigationBarTaller.heightIncrease/2

        ///Transform all view to shift upward for [shift] point
        self.transform =
            CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -shift)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let shift = UINavigationBarTaller.heightIncrease/2

        ///Move the background down for [shift] point
        let classNamesToReposition: [String] = ["_UINavigationBarBackground"]
        for view: UIView in self.subviews {
            if classNamesToReposition.contains(NSStringFromClass(view.dynamicType)) {
                let bounds: CGRect = self.bounds
                var frame: CGRect = view.frame
                frame.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + shift - 20.0
                frame.size.height = bounds.size.height + 20.0
                view.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        let amendedSize:CGSize = super.sizeThatFits(size)
        let newSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(amendedSize.width, UINavigationBarTaller.navigationBarHeight);
        return newSize;
    }
}
```

Also on my gist: https://gist.github.com/pai911/8fa123d4068b61ad0ff7

**iOS 10 Update:**

Unfortunately, this code breaks in iOS 10, there is someone who helps fix it, here you go:

[iOS 10 custom navigation bar height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454548/ios-10-custom-navigation-bar-height)

And to be clear, this code is kind of hacky since it depends on the navigation bar's internal structure...so if you decide to use it anyway, be prepared for any upcoming changes that may break this code...

Comment: Incredible. Great job! Any ideas on how to add an image as a logo in the center of the Navbar? Or text?

Comment: Ps, mind explaining why you're using all the initialize functions?

Comment: That will transform all the coordinates of the navigation bar upwards for [shift] points  (there are two params in CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation, , the 1st one is for x, the 2nd one is for Y)

Comment: for adding a logo in the navigation bar, pls see this tutorial:

http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/customizing-navigation-bar-ios8-swift

Comment: During modal transition it will jump a little, still pretty great answer

Answer (score 2):

Great answer from **Bon Bon**!

In Swift 3 however make sure you replace

```
let classNamesToReposition: [String] = ["_UINavigationBarBackground"]
```

with

```
let classNamesToReposition: [ String ] = [ "_UIBarBackground" ]
```

Otherwise, it wont work.

Comment: Thanks for the update! there is also a post with full code sample. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39454548/ios-10-custom-navigation-bar-height

and I updated my original post, cheeres